# How to show that a subset of a Ring is an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

My book says that $I$ is an idea of a right $R$ if

1. $I$ is an additive subgroup of $R$
2. $ra \in I$ and $ar \in I$ for any $r\in R$ and $a \in I$

Both conditions are straightforward checks, but I do not recall the definition of additive subgroup, or every learning it. Nor can I find it in my book... The only thing that comes to mind is that for the first condition that it is sufficient to show closure of $+, -, *$ Is that indeed sufficient?

Could somebody show an example of the first condition?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means that it is an abelian group under the addition law defined in the ring

Comment: Just ignore the additive part. One could just say that $I$ is a subgroup of $R$. If the operation of $R$ is 'multiplication', then one would want $I$ to be a (multiplicative) subgroup of $R$. Similarly, if the operation of $R$ is 'addition', one would want $I$ to be an (additive) subgroup of $R$. The multiplicative/additive part just emphasizes the operation in $R$. But all you really care about is that $I$ is a subgroup of $R$. Note your second condition implies that you are defining a two-sided ideal $I$.

Comment: A ring $(R,+,\cdot)$ with identity has two substructures: the abelian group $(R,+)$ and the monoid $(R,\cdot)$. It's entirely possible for multiplicative groups to exist inside $(R,\cdot)$, so it's necessary to say "additive" to draw your attention and emphasize that we're talking about a subgroup of $(R,+)$.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring then $R$ with it's addition operation is an abelian group.  A subgroup of this abelian group is what *additive subgroup* refers to.  So to check that $I$ is an ideal it must be

1. Nonempty
2. Closed under $+$.
3. Closed under multiplication from $R$ ($a \in R, r \in I \Rightarrow ar, ra \in I$)

The first two conditions are part of checking that $I$ is an additive subgroup.  To show that it's an additive subgroup you technically must also show it is closed under taking inverses, i.e., $r \in I \Rightarrow -r \in I$.  This is taken care of by choosing $a = -1$ in the third condition.

Also, fyi, this is what's called a *two sided* ideal.  For left ideals you only require $ar \in I$ in the third condition and for right ideals you only require $ra \in I$.  If $R$ is a commutative ring then there's no difference between left, right, and two sided ideals.

Comment: Wouldn't you actually want to show that $I$ is closed under subtraction to ensure that it is actually a subgroup? EDIT: It seems your edit and my comment were simultaneous. :)

Comment: See my edit, which explains why this is automatic.

Comment: Can I just do, Nonempty, closure of $+, -, *$ and then the last condition?

Comment: Sure, but why do closure of $-$ and $*$ if the last condition takes care of both of those?

Comment: What if there is no element $-1$ in the ring? I know there are multiple definitions of rings too...

Comment: That's a good point, I always assume rings have an identity.  Closure under $*$ is still fine, but I'm not sure about closure under $-$, you might have to check it separately.

Comment: @Jim The problem with this version is that the subgroup criteria has been made to depend on the multiplication and existence of a unit. This can be fixed (and probably should be) by adding a criterion. Notice that $\mathbb  N\subseteq \mathbb Z$ satsifies your first two criterion, but it' isn't a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. If you add "closed under negation," then everything is good.

Comment: @Jim But in your defense, as the question is stated in the OP, I think the book is assuming an identity exists, and that this is exactly what it was looking for! +1